Excel - Ranking consecutively with duplicate values
Please see image below the "Numbers" column are the values I want to rank. 
The "Preferred Ranking" is what I want as the results except I am having real trouble trying to get there!
Do you have any idea how I can achieve this? Thanks in advance.


Which version of Excel do you have?

Hi - I use Excel 365

=SUM(1*(A1>=UNIQUE($A$1:$A$17))) and drag it down or =MAP(A1:A17,LAMBDA(z,SUM(1*(z>=UNIQUE(A1:A17))))) to spill whole result at once.
Result:


Just out of curiosity, if Column A's values were descending highest values, how would the SUM/UNIQUE formula vary?

Do you want to rank in reverse order?

Use UNIQUE to return a unique list.
This will spill down the range:
=LET(
    RNG,A2:A22,
    BYROW(RNG,LAMBDA(Z,COUNT(UNIQUE(FILTER(RNG,RNG<Z)))+1))
    ) 



Simpler way is using XMATCH() with SORT() and UNIQUE().
=XMATCH(A1,SORT(UNIQUE($A$1:$A$20)))


This could be even simpler =XMATCH(A1,UNIQUE($A$1:$A$20)) if values are already sorted as seen in OP's example. Brilliant!

@user11222393 Yes, but in case of unsorted data it will rank wrongly. Thats why, I have used SORT() function.
